# MVC Dynamic Form Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have read this article which shows how to display dynamic fields via the use of editor templates http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

How can I create new fields by clicking an "Add Field" button?

I have googled this and looked at some examples but they seem way too complex for what should be a simple process.  In PHP, you would simply append `[]` to the end of the field name and you could then run it through a loop...

There should be an even simpler way to do this in MVC since it's newer tech, right?

Comment: Take a look at this post, it may not be exactly what you are looking for but it may shed some light http://roysvork.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/dynamic-repeating-field-groups-in-asp-net-mvc-with-just-a-dash-of-knockout-js/

Comment: Thanks, but I have already seen that one.  It uses knockout.js, which I don't.

Comment: Did you find a way out?

Comment: @shyamalparikh Wow it's such a coincidence that you posted that comment when you did, I just needed to do dynamic form fields a couple days ago and this question is two years old!  See my answer below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic form fields can be accomplished as easy as follows:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.TextboxFor(m => m.Name)

@* you can add as many of these as you like, or add them via javascript *@
<input type="text" name="EmailAddresses" />
<input type="text" name="EmailAddresses" />
<input type="text" name="EmailAddresses" />
@* you can also use razor syntax *@
@Html.Textbox("EmailAddresses")
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    // note that model.EmailAddresses contains your list of email addresses
    foreach (string email in model.EmailAddresses)
        email = email; // do whatever you want with this...

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Does this work with client side validation? For example can we add [Required] in the ViewModel and MVC would take care with @ValidationMessageFor ?

Comment: @shyamalparikh Yes, it will effect ModelState just like any other form you submit in MVC.  Note:  I changed `EmailAddresses[]` to `EmailAddresses`, it appears MVC doesn't require the brackets and including them will break it.

Comment: I can't believe this works. Can someone explain what is the reasoning behind this? Why it works when you use name="EmailAddresses" but if you go for asp-for="@Model.Emailaddresses" it doesn't ?

Comment: @knil4_crack Not sure, but it kind of works out because it has the added advantage of being able to add them via JavaScript which is a pretty common use case if you are generating these from some server-side data i.e. user clicks a dropdown and the checkboxes change based on their input.